# OS memory allocation addresses

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

Quick curious question, memory allocation addresses are choosed by the language compiler or is it the OS which chooses the addresses for the memory asked?

This is from a doubt about virtual memory, where it could be quickly explained as "let the process think he owns all the memory", but what happens on 64 bits architectures where only 48 bits are used for memory addresses if the process wants a higher address?

Lets say you do a `int a = malloc(sizeof(int));` and you have no memory left from the previous system call so you need to ask the OS for more memory, is the compiler the one who determines the memory address to allocate this variable, or does it just ask the OS for memory and it allocates it on the address returned by it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would not be the compiler, especially since this is dynamic memory allocation. Compilation is done well before you actually execute your program.

Memory reservation for static variables happens at compile time. But the static memory allocation will happen at start-up, before the user defined Main.

Static variables can be given space in the executable file itself, this would then be memory mapped into the process address space. This is only one of few times(?) I can image the compiler actually "deciding" on an address.

During dynamic memory allocation your program would ask the OS for some memory and it is the OS that returns a memory address. This address is then stored in a pointer for example.

Answer (score 0):

The *dynamic* memory allocation in C/C++ is simply done by runtime library functions. Those functions can do pretty much as they please as long as their behavior is standards-compliant. A trivial implementation of compliant but useless `malloc()` looks like this:

```
void * malloc(size_t size) {
    return NULL;
}
```

The requirements are fairly relaxed -- the pointer has to be suitably aligned and the pointers must be unique unless they've been previously `free()d`. You could have a rather silly but somewhat portable and absolutely not thread-safe memory allocator done the way below. There, the addresses come from a pool that was decided upon by the compiler.

```
#include "stdint.h"
// 1/4 of available address space, but at most 2^30.
#define HEAPSIZE (1UL << ( ((sizeof(void*)>4) ? 4 : sizeof(void*)) * 2 ))
// A pseudo-portable alignment size for pointerŚbwitary types. Breaks
// when faced with SIMD data types.
#define ALIGNMENT (sizeof(intptr_t) > sizeof(double) ? sizeof(intptr_t) : siE   1Azeof(double))

void * malloc(size_t size)
{
    static char buffer[HEAPSIZE];
    static char * next = NULL;
    void * result;
    if (next == NULL) {
        uintptr_t ptr = (uintptr_t)buffer;
        ptr += ptr % ALIGNMENT;
        next = (char*)ptr;
    }
    if (size == 0) return NULL;
    if (next-buffer > HEAPSIZE-size) return NULL;
    result = next;
    next += size;
    next += size % ALIGNMENT;
    return result;
}

void free(void * ptr)
{}
```

Practical memory allocators don't depend upon such static memory pools, but rather call the OS to provide them with newly mapped memory.

The proper way of thinking about it is: you don't know what *particular* pointer you are going to get from `malloc()`. You can only know that it's unique and points to properly aligned memory if you've called `malloc()` with a non-zero argument. That's all.